# Is the following C code safe?

Tags: c

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* ptr=NULL;
    printf("%s",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints (null) as output.
The above is a sample code. In real code i get char* as a return of a function and i wish to print the character string for logging. However, NULL is also a valid return value of that function and so i am wondering if a null check is required before printing the character string?

```
char* ptr=someFuncion();
// do i need the following if statement?
if(ptr!=NULL)
{
  printf("%s",ptr);
}
```

I just want to be sure that the output would be same i.e if ptr=NULL then output should be (null) on all platforms and compilers and the above code(without if statement) would not crash on any C standard compatible platform.

In short, is the above code(without the if statement) standard compatible?

Thanks for your help and patience :)

Regards

lali

Comment: What's the `<stdlib.h>` header providing to your code?  Your code invokes undefined behaviour by passing a null pointer to a function that does not expect one.  Anything may happen - including it might accidentally work, mostly.

Comment: ok, i got that. Thank you all for such "realtime" help :))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> In short, is the above code(without
>   the if statement) standard compatible?

No. ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (the C standard document) makes no statement about what should happen if `ptr` is NULL, so the behaviour is *undefined*. The library you used merely was friendly enough to give you some helpful output ("(null)") instead of crashing.

Include the explicit check for NULL.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean something like this?

```
  char* result = foo ();
  printf ("result is %s\n", (result ? result : "NULL"));
```

Answer (score 5):

In case of doubt you should not rely on implementation details and perform an additional `(ptr != NULL)` - it's also good coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll be in the clear without the if-statement, in my experience, although I tend to avoid doing what you illustrated out of habit... it's been a long time, but IIRC the Sun compilers I used to work with would result in a crash some or all of the time if you passed a NULL char* into printf(), so it's just easier and safer to include the check... I was going to throw in the note about using the macro-form, but I see I've been beaten to it by like 3 other people in the 30 seconds since I started typing this :)